# Connect AWS API Gateway to an internal NLB backed by ECS Microservice

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I seem to be stuck with my architecture for ECS Microservices.
Current State :

[image]

1. ECS cluster with 2 EC2 instances in private subnets exposing a dockerized node express endpoint on port 3000 (1 service, 2 running tasks)
2. NAT gateway route out from VPC's default route table
3. internal NLB in front of those 2 EC2 instances.
4. VPC Link created in API Gateway for targeting the NLB.
5. API gateway integration with the VPC link (what do I enter as the endpoint URI? is it the DNS of the NLB? or custom domain name in step 6)
6. Created custom domain name for the API gateway

when I try to send a request to customdomainname:3000/task. I expected the task to be run However I do not get any response(There was an error connecting to customdomainname:3000/task).

Everything works perfectly fine if its an internet facing Application load balancer and instances in public subnet, but I need to use the VPC link approach to secure my application.

I understand my question might be vague, but I would appreciate any input and insights from anyone who has worked on this before

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: AWS CloudFront as a single door to access everything might solve your problem. You can use CloudFront to request/response from internal network without exposing your web server to world.